# How to truncate text in a flex container(With properties in the text to truncate already placed)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

As the title says,this is the problem. (Before I've taken a look at all the questions/answers there are about this topic but they don't solve my problem)

I have a template area called `testItem` which it's a flex container and inside this I've got a `h6` element and it has the css properties: `overflow: hidden`, `white-space: nowrap` and `text-overflow: ellipsis` so it so I should have truncated the text but not and this moves the containers below (I don't want this).

The flex container, which template area is called `testItem` continue growing by its content (the `h6` element) but is not truncated.

I've tried: add `min-width:0` property to the flex container or `flex: 1`, `flex-grow: 0` but it doesn't work. The only possibility is to put `max-width: Xpx` but that's not good enough because of If I've got a long text with a big screen resolution, this text decentralize the rest of the containers...

**I want to truncate the text in X resolution so that the container does not continue growing for this content and that the rest of elements remain fixed (but that this is responsive, therefore I can not use fixed units)**

*Note: If you need further clarification I have no problem resolving them :)*

*Note2: I attached a CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/03o4x2r33n*

**Thanks in advance!**

The attached code and its execution

```css
.tagsItem {
  grid-area: tags-item;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.testItem {
  grid-area: test-item;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.firstDatesItem {
  grid-area: first-dates-item;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.secondDatesItem {
  grid-area: second-dates-item;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.datesItem {
  grid-area: dates-item;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.patientItem {
  grid-area: patient-item;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.endoscopyContainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "tags-item test-item dates-item patient-item";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 3.5fr 3.5fr;
  column-gap: 0.5em;
  justify-items: start;
  align-items: center;
}

.dividerContainer {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.priorityCard {
  height: 1.8em;
  width: 8em;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  background: #e5737347;
}

.statusCard {
  height: 1.8em;
  width: 8em;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
}

.applicationTypeCard {
  height: 1.8em;
  width: 8em;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  background: #9ecd601f;
}

.testCodeLabel {
  color: grey;
}

.testNameLabel {
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="endoscopyContainer">
  <div class="tagsItem">
    <h6 class="priorityCard">Example</h6>
    <h6 class="statusCard">Example2</h6>
    <h6 class="applicationTypeCard">Example3</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="testItem">
    <h6 class="testNameLabel">
      Text that I want to truncate but is still growing its container because of it
    </h6>
    <h6 class="testCodeLabel">12312ASD</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="datesItem">
    Dates ExampleDates ExampleDates ExampleDates ExampleDates ExampleDates ExampleDates ExampleDates ExampleDates ExampleDates ExampleDates ExampleDates Example
  </div>
  <div class="patientItem">
    Patient ExamplePatient ExamplePatient ExamplePatient ExamplePatient ExamplePatient ExamplePatient ExamplePatient ExamplePatient ExamplePatient ExamplePatient
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have *invalid* css - only one set of quotes in the `grid-template-areas` is required, and for `grid-area` quotes are not required... see [corrected sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l0mn1935m)

Comment: Yes, I've fixed it! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a width propertie to your testNameLabel like so:

```
.testNameLabel {
  width: 15vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```css
.tagsItem {
  grid-area: "tags-item";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.testItem {
  grid-area: "test-item";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.firstDatesItem {
  grid-area: "first-dates-item";
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.secondDatesItem {
  grid-area: "second-dates-item";
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.datesItem {
  grid-area: "dates-item";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.patientItem {
  grid-area: "patient-item";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.endoscopyContainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: '"tags-item test-item dates-item patient-item"';
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 3.5fr 3.5fr;
  column-gap: 0.5em;
  justify-items: start;
  align-items: center;
}

.dividerContainer {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.priorityCard {
  height: 1.8em;
  width: 8em;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  background: #e5737347;
}

.statusCard {
  height: 1.8em;
  width: 8em;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
}

.applicationTypeCard {
  height: 1.8em;
  width: 8em;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  background: #9ecd601f;
}

.testCodeLabel {
  color: grey;
}

.testNameLabel {
 width: 15vw;
 font-weight: bold;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="endoscopyContainer">
      <div class="tagsItem">
        <h6 class="priorityCard">Example</h6>
        <h6 class="statusCard">Example2</h6>
        <h6 class="applicationTypeCard">Example3</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="testItem">
        <h6 class="testNameLabel">
          Text that I want to truncate but is still growing its container
          because of it
        </h6>
        <h6 class="testCodeLabel">12312ASD</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="datesItem">
        Dates ExampleDates ExampleDates ExampleDates ExampleDates ExampleDates
        ExampleDates ExampleDates ExampleDates ExampleDates ExampleDates
        ExampleDates Example
      </div>
      <div class="patientItem">
        Patient ExamplePatient ExamplePatient ExamplePatient ExamplePatient
        ExamplePatient ExamplePatient ExamplePatient ExamplePatient
        ExamplePatient ExamplePatient
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @MaximeB! It's a good solution with plain screen but the problem is that to the left I have a contextual menu so if I opened it the text would remain overlayed because it would be in the 16vw :S

Comment: I've tried it and it works well! You've my 10! Thank you so much!

Comment: That's good to hear. I'm glad i can help!